# Scala syntax with complex polymorphism bounds

Tags: scala, polymorphism

Is there a scala mechanism to simplify long polymorphism bounds? for example:

```scala
case class RecordTypeX(...) extends A with B with C with D with E with F // defined in my project
case class RecordTypey(...) extends A with B with C with D with E with F // defined in a dependency package

class MyClass1[T <: A with B with C with D with E with F](x:T) {...}
class MyClass2[T <: A with B with C with D with E with F](x:T) {...}
...

val x = RecordTypeX(...)
val y = RecordTypeY(...)
val instance = new MyClass1(x)
val instance = new MyClass1(y)
```

Ideally, it would be nice to have something like

```scala
type Processable=A with B with C with D with E with F
case class RecordTypeX(...) extends Processable // defined in my project
case class RecordTypeY(...) extends A with B with C with D with E with F // defined in a dependency package

class MyClass1[T <: Processable]() {...}
class MyClass2[T <: Processable]() {...}
...

val x = RecordTypeX(...)
val y = RecordTypeY(...)
val instance = new MyClass1(x)
val instance = new MyClass1(y)
```

Any solution?

Note:
Introducing a new trait that combine all other traits and extending it for all the possible classes such as

```scala
trait Processable extends A with B with C with D with E with F
```

cannot be a solution because I can not modify RecordTypeY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a combination of both.

```
trait A
trait B
trait C
trait D
trait E
trait F

type Processable = A with B with C with D with E with F
trait ProcessableI extends A with B with C with D with E with F

final case class RecordTypeX(s: String) extends ProcessableI
final case class RecordTypeY(i: Int) extends A with B with C with D with E with F

class MyClass[T <: Processable](x: T)

val x = RecordTypeX("foo")
val y = RecordTypeY(3)
val instance1 = new MyClass(x)
val instance2 = new MyClass(y)
```